# HTML5 canvas fillText margins

Tags: html, animation, canvas, margins

Is there any way of adding some kind of automatic margin between two or more `fillText()`?

I have a set of `fillText()` that is changing every frame, they become longer and shorter, but I would want them to to have a fixed space between the text. I don't know how else I can explain this. I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tv44ja5/2/) to show what I mean.

Example, if you look at the seconds counter, when there is only 1 character in there, the 'S' character is longer away from the seconds than it should.

How would I fix this? I'm pretty new to canvas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found a solution. I'm now grabbing the width of each text element and using that, plus some more in the second argument of `fillText()`.

https://jsfiddle.net/9tv44ja5/3/

^ Updated solution. It's a bit messy atm., will try to clean it up abit later.